# Отправить SendMessage калькулятору

Tags: c#, winapi

Как отправить `SendMessage` на нужный элемент стороннему приложению, у которого 1 дескриптор на родительское окно, а элементы управления без своих дескрипторов (handle=0).

Пример - калькулятор в Windows 10.

`UIA` не предлагать, т.к. оно требует фокус в приложении, мне нужно чтобы это работало на свёрнутом приложении.

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static class WinAPI

        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

        }

        const int BM_CLICK = 0xF5;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr hwndMain = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "Калькулятор");
            IntPtr button = WinAPI.FindWindowEx(hwndMain, IntPtr.Zero, null, "Два");

            WinAPI.SendMessage(button, BM_CLICK, 0, null);

            MessageBox.Show(button.ToString());

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Для чего именно вы пишете кликер? Если это DirectX приложение (игра), то все тренировки на калькуляторах ни к чему не приведут, так как способ обработки ввода мыши и клавы у игр никак не связан с MessageLoop. И на свернутом окне эмулировать ввод не получится чисто технически. Вы не первый, кому я здесь отвечаю на этот же вопрос, просто вы зашли издалека. Ну или расскажите, какая цель этого всего, если я ошибся.

Comment: @aepot , это не игра и не DirectX, конкретный пример - калькулятор. В свёрнутое окно блокнота я на изи отправляю текст в редактор через этот же SendMessage, чисто технически, так сказать. У калькулятора другой тип, поэтому возник вопрос - как.

Comment: Просто в блокноте поле редактирования имеет свой дескриптор, а в калькуляторе как понимаю главный дескриптор и элементы без дескрипторов. Вот и спросила, как к ним обращаться если дескрипторов нет как таковых у них. @aepot

Comment: Если вы проверили и убедились что кнопки у калькулятора это точно не контролы (не имеют дескрипторов окна), попробуйте отправлять события WM_KEYDOWN и WP_KEYUP. Это должно сработать, т.к. калькулятор обрабатывает нажатия с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу скажу, что не претендую на верное решение, но я писал кликер под WOW (Анти афк), и работал он со свернутым приложением, написано под 2 кнопки (можно прожать например shift-3), под калькулятор переделать проблем не составит, я думаю. Если что-то неправильно понял - сильно не пинайте))

```
 public class KeysTest
        {

            const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
            const uint Key_Down = 0x0001;
            const uint Key_Up = 0x0002;
            private volatile bool _shouldStop;
            private Process _sroProcess;
            private Keys _modefirKey;
            private Keys _pressKey;

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


            public KeysTest(Process targetSro, Keys modKey, Keys pressKey)
            {
                _sroProcess = targetSro;
                _modefirKey = modKey;
                _pressKey = pressKey;
            }

            public void SendKeys()
            {
                SendKeyWithModefir(_sroProcess, (byte)_modefirKey, (byte)_pressKey);
            }

            public void SendKeyWithModefir(Process _p, byte ModKey, byte PressKey)
            {
                while (!_shouldStop)
                {
                    keybd_event(ModKey, 0, Key_Down, 0);
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    PostMessage(_p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)(PressKey), (IntPtr)(0));
                    PostMessage(_p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)(PressKey), (IntPtr)(0));
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    keybd_event(ModKey, 0, Key_Up, 0);
                }
            }

            public void RequestStop()
            {
                _shouldStop = true;
            }

            ~KeysTest()
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
        private KeysTest sendingKeys;
        private Thread startSending;
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Тут был таймер, но я его убрал для читаемости
            Process[] s = Process.GetProcessesByName("Wow");
            sendingKeys = new KeysTest(s[0], Keys.A, Keys.D);
            startSending = new Thread(sendingKeys.SendKeys);
            startSending.Start();
            while (!startSending.IsAlive) ;
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            sendingKeys.RequestStop();
            startSending.Join();
            startSending.Abort();
        }
```

Comment: Тут Вы просто передаёте PostMessage в дескриптор главного окна игры. С калькулятором так не выйдет, так как нужно передать сообщение в дескриптор кнопки, а у кнопок нет дескрипторов )

Comment: Ааа, Вам непосредственно кликнуть надо на кнопку, я думал просто какие то действия выполнить (2+3), тогда надо подумать.

Comment: @AnnaErmilova вы пытаетесь узнать что-то об интерфейсе с помощью Win API, которая ничего не знает об это интерфейсе, так как его рендерит не система, а само приложение. То есть на уровне системы это просто прямоугольник окна, а что внутри - неизвестно. Следовательно единственный способ ткнуть в кнопку - это передать туда клик мышью в нужные координаты, или нажать клавишу на клавиатуре. То что вы пытаетесь решить, выбранным вами способом не решается. Создайте UWP приложение, добавьте в окно кнопку, и станет ясно, что контрола в понимании системы там нет. Калькулятор - это UWP приложение.

Comment: @AnnaErmilova второй вариант, поищите, как ваша задача решается средствами WinRT, а не WinAPI, быть может если десктопная часть винды про UWP ничего не знает, то может RT часть знает, я не копался, это просто идея.

Comment: @AnnaErmilova ну и самый жесткий вариант - залезть в память другого приложения, найти данные его интерфейса, найти там нужный контрол с помощью рефлексии, и просто дернуть ему событие `Click`. Но это задача максимальной сложности, я лишь в теории предполагаю, что такое возможно.

Comment: @aepot , а в UIA нет возможности передавать команды без фокуса в окне? Тоесть прямо в свёрнутое.

Comment: @AnnaErmilova чтобы что-то отправить окну на уровне системы, надо использовать те же сообщения. Ваша задача имеет только одно универсальное решение. Ставите виртуальную машину, запускаете внутри нее развернутое в фокусе приложение и свой кликер, сворачиваете окно виртуальной машины, и готово. Других решений я не знаю.